# How to disable registration of new users in Phoenix?

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to disable registration of new users in Phoenix. How to do that?

For example, if I just comment out this route:

```
# get "/registration", UserRegistrationController, :new
# post "/registration", UserRegistrationController, :create
```

I get this error:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function BlogWeb.Router.Helpers.user_registration_path/2 is undefined or private
```

and it points to the file: `_user_menu.html.heex`

So, if simple commenting out of routes is not an option, how to do that?

My goal is to have toggle on/off switch for allowing loggin in by new users but for now, even a simple hardcoded way of doing things would be enough.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the router endpoint will change what is generated in by the helpers module. It appears that you are trying to use the non existent endpoint somewhere else in your code though. Possibly another html.eex file. Its hard to say without the full context though.